# converting list into array for values stored in a variable

Tags: linux, shell, unix, hive, scripting

I have a configuration file. the first column is job name and rest of the column are tables associated with that job. now i am reading the first row. it will check for the job name and tables associated with it in the . now these tables i want to loop through and create a HQL query. the issue with my code is tables are getting stored in a variable as list and when i an executing unset command it's throwing error. can anyone help me where i went wrong. below is the configuration file, code and required output.

```
job1,tbl1,tbl2,tbl3
job2.tbl4,tbl5,tbl6
job3,tbl7,tbl8,tbl9
```

Below is the code which i am trying

```
    #!/bin/bash

while read line; do
    job_name=$(echo "$line"|awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}{print $1}')
    echo "JobName is $job_name"
    tablestring=${line#"$job_name"}
    for table in ${tablestring//,/ }; do
        echo "$table"
    done
hql="select $table as table_name, max(cycle_Date) as AS_OF_dATE FROM DB1.$table "
unset tablestring[0]
for tbl in "${tablestring[@]}"
do
hql+=$'\n'
hql+="union all select $tbl as table_name, max(cycle_Date) as AS_OF_dATE FROM DB1.$tbl"
hql+=";"
echo "$hql" >query.hql
done
done < a.configuration
```

Below is the required output which i want to achieve in the first iteration for job 1 and successively for job 2 and so on..

```
  select tbl1 as table_name, max(cycle_Date) as AS_OF_dATE FROM DB1.tbl1
    union all select tbl2 as table_name, max(cycle_Date) as AS_OF_dATE FROM DB1.tbl2
    union all select tbl3 as table_name, max(cycle_Date) as AS_OF_dATE FROM DB1.tbl3;
```

Comment: Well, "tablestring" is not an array in this script. Questions : do you control/write the configuration file or is it generated by another process ?, What do you expect in the query.hql ... only one select statement (so 1 file per job) or all select statements for all the jobs ? Finally, you don't seems to use the job name except for display while the script runs...am I right ?

Comment: @AndreGelinas.. i write the configuration.. yes correct .. separate query.hql for each job.. will execute the hql file and delete it.. later another query.hql needs to be generated for another jobs with the required tables..job name is just for display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would use this as the configuration file a.cfg

```
job[1]="jobname1 tbl1 tbl2 tbl3"
job[2]="jobname2 tbl4 tbl5 tbl6 tbl7"
job[3]="jobname3 tbl8 tbl9"
```

And this script

```
#!/bin/bash

TimeStamp=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

#Sourcing the configuration file. Here in the same directory as this script but you can provide the full path
. ./a.cfg

for i in ${!job[@]}; do
    #Creating the array jobtable. The job name is always index 0
    jobtable=( ${job[$i]} )
    #Using a unique name for each file
    filename=${TimeStamp}_${jobtable[0]}.hql
    echo "Processing ${jobtable[0]} using"
    for ((j=1;j<${#jobtable[@]};j++)); do
        echo "    ${jobtable[$j]}"
        #Creating the hql file
        if [[ $j -eq 1 ]]; then
            echo "select ${jobtable[$j]} as table_name, max(cycle_Date) as AS_OF_dATE FROM DB1.${jobtable[$j]} " >> $filename
        elif [[ $j -lt $((${#jobtable[@]}-1)) ]]; then
            echo " union all select ${jobtable[$j]} as table_name, max(cycle_Date) as AS_OF_dATE FROM DB1.${jobtable[$j]}" >> $filename
        else
            echo " union all select ${jobtable[$j]} as table_name, max(cycle_Date) as AS_OF_dATE FROM DB1.${jobtable[$j]};" >> $filename
        fi
    done
    #You can use the newly created hql file here using $filename. I would not delete the file though as it might be usefull to
    #troubleshoot if something is not right.
done
```

It does produce the hql files like this one

```
select tbl1 as table_name, max(cycle_Date) as AS_OF_dATE FROM DB1.tbl1
 union all select tbl2 as table_name, max(cycle_Date) as AS_OF_dATE FROM DB1.tbl2
 union all select tbl3 as table_name, max(cycle_Date) as AS_OF_dATE FROM DB1.tbl3;
```

EDIT : small edit to correct a typo.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am facing one issue. I created exact same configuration but while sourcing the file it's throwing permission denied. I tried to change it by adding  chmod u+r+x a.configuration and then ../a.configuration in the script.. still i am getting permission denied error.. i checked the file properties and all access are given to the file

Comment: Just to be sure, in your comment it says "../a.configuration" with 2 dots instead of only 1. Is that a typo ? Because that could be the source of the permission denied. The sourcing line is ". ./a.cfg" with a space between the first 2 dots, just to be clear